# Generate JSON with property names that include dot in SQL

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

I need to generate the following JSON payload (shortened) from a table in SQL Server. Please note the dot in the property name. This is a special syntax called OData.

```
{
  "Id" : "A1",
  "new_cluster": {
      "spark_conf":{
         "spark.master":"local[0]",
         "spark.databricks.cluster.profile": "singleNode"
       }
  }
}
```

I have tried the following T-SQL command:

```
SELECT @id as ID, @name1 AS [new_cluster.spark_conf.spark.master]
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

Which obviously results to:

```
{
  "Id" : "A1",
  "new_cluster": {
    "spark_conf": {
      "spark": {
         "master":  "local[0]"
       }
    }
  }
}
```

I have already read the full documentation around JSON functionality in SQL Server thoroughly and no where in the documentation escaping dot in property names has been described.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if using `FOR JSON PATH` directly is a working solution. The documentation explains, that *... The FOR JSON PATH clause uses the column alias or column name to determine the key name in the JSON output. If an alias contains dots, the PATH option creates nested objects. ...*, so this behaviour is expected. Possible workarounds in this situation are:

Using `JSON_MODIFY()`:

```
DECLARE @id varchar(2) = 'A1'
DECLARE @name1 varchar(10) = 'local[0]'
SELECT 
   @id as ID, 
   JSON_MODIFY('{}', '$."spark.master"', @name1) AS [new_cluster.spark_conf]
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

A combination of `FOR JSON PATH` and `FOR JSON AUTO`:

```
DECLARE @id varchar(2) = 'A1'
DECLARE @name1 varchar(10) = 'local[0]'
SELECT 
   @id as ID, 
   JSON_QUERY((
      SELECT @name1 AS [spark.master]
      FROM (VALUES (NULL)) v (v)
      FOR JSON AUTO, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
   )) AS [new_cluster.spark_conf]
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

Result:

```
{"ID":"A1","new_cluster":{"spark_conf":{"spark.master":"local[0]"}}}
```

A note about the new SQL Server 2022 JSON features. If I can trust the documentation, the newly introduced [`JSON_OBJECT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-object-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function will (probably) provide another option:

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
   'Id': @id,
   'new_cluster': JSON_OBJECT('spark_conf': JSON_OBJECT('spark.master': @name1))
)
```